# Android, RecyclerView - Do something with invisible items

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I'm using `recyclerView` to implement `ExpandableList` and I want when user clicks on `parent` view, other expanded parents collapse. It works nice with code below:

```
private void collapseOthers(int position) {
        for (int i = 0; i < ol.size(); i++) {
            OrderForShow o = ol.get(i);
            if (i != position) {
                if (!o.isChild()) {
                    if (o.getChilds() == null) {
                        RecyclerView.ViewHolder vh = rView.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(i);
                        if (vh != null)
                            vh.itemView.findViewById(R.id.root_layer).performClick();

                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

but when user scrolls down, upper items will be null and `vh` goes null and I can't collapse invisible item, Is there any way to handle this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Try assigning ids to the layout (or item within layout) inside `onBindViewHolder` and make changes on basis of id only.

Another alternative is to maintain a `HashMap<Integer,String>`  where Integer will be the position of the item and String can be used to store it's status like "visible" or "invisible".

This is because while scrolling, very often, internally RecyclerView does make some mess in maintaining the dirty views and maintain their ids. Better, we maintain it and take control of them.

This [link](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/user_interface/recyclerview/) explains how RecyclerView works.